# A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:compileDebugAidl' (type 'AidlCompile')

Tags: unreal-engine5

When packagind the project for quest2,its throwing this error!
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): * What went wrong:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:compileDebugAidl' (type 'AidlCompile').
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): > File 'C:\Users\czars\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\framework.aidl' specified for property 'aidlFrameworkProvider' does not exist.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): 1 actionable task: 1 executed
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): * Try:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org/
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): BUILD FAILED in 7s
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): ERROR: cmd.exe failed with args /c "C:\Users\czars\ue projects\gradlebatch\Intermediate\Android\arm64\gradle\rungradle.bat" :app:assembleDebug
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):        (see C:\Users\czars\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_5.0\Log.txt for full exception trace)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): AutomationTool executed for 0h 0m 36s
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=1 (Error_Unknown)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Updating environment variables set by a Turnkey sub-process
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): The system cannot find the path specified.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): The system cannot find the path specified.
PackagingResults: Error: cmd.exe failed with args /c "C:\Users\czars\ue projects\gradlebatch\Intermediate\Android\arm64\gradle\rungradle.bat" :app:assembleDebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error raises when Android sdk, API level, sdk tools , gradle plugin versions aren't compatible.
I'm building a project for metaquest-2 with android API level-29.
Android studio Version-4.0
For this :

1. Make sure configuration is as shown in below
   **gradle.build(Project:My_Application):**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    
        plugins {
            id 'com.android.application' version '6.5.1' apply false
            id 'com.android.library' version '6.5.1' apply false
            id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false }
```

**gradle.build(Module:My_Application.app):**

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    }
    
    android {
        namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
        compileSdk 29
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
            minSdk 23
            //noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
            targetSdk 29
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
        buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
        ndkVersion '21.4.7075529'
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
        //noinspection GradleDependency
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    }
```